# Custom navigation bar back button hit area

Tags: ios, user-interface, uinavigationbar

1. I have implement custom back Navigation bar button.
2. Codes:

   -(UIBarButtonItem*) logicToAddBackButton    {

   ```
   UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UiNavigationBack"]];

   UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc] init];

   [label setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0]];
   [label setText:@"Home"];
   [label sizeToFit];

   int space=6;
   label.frame=CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x+imageView.frame.size.width+space, label.frame.origin.y, label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height);
   UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, label.frame.size.width+imageView.frame.size.width+space, imageView.frame.size.height)];

   view.bounds=CGRectMake(view.bounds.origin.x+8, view.bounds.origin.y-1, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height);
   [view addSubview:imageView];
   [view addSubview:label];

   UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:view.frame];
   [button addTarget:self action:@selector(eventBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [view addSubview:button];

   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.33 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
       label.alpha = 0.0;
       CGRect orig=label.frame;
       label.frame=CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x+25, label.frame.origin.y, label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height);
       label.alpha = 1.0;
       label.frame=orig;
   } completion:nil];

   UIBarButtonItem *backButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:view];

   return backButton;
   ```

   }

   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self logicToAddBackButton];
3. This is how it look and work fine according to the logic.
   [image]
4. Issue: If we click on first half of arrow, the back button do not respond.
5. Please suggest on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set to your button:

```
button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(<#CGFloat top#>, <#CGFloat left#>, <#CGFloat bottom#>, <#CGFloat right#>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you miscalculating frame somewhere.
Why don't you add UIButton instead? It will be much easier, but without label animation.

```
  UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(eventBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"Home" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UiNavigationBack"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button sizeToFit];
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

    return backButton;
```

Comment: It doesn't give look and feel as default navigation back button. The space between arrow and name and mainly starting point.